# After I delete a Record from Firebase, Android studios is leading me to very first activity

Tags: firebase, android-studio

After deleting a record in firebase , Firebase is leading me to the very last activity in the android studio's activity stack, I dont know why this is happening.

```
 removeProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Task<Void> mTask = databaseReference.child("cart").child(bundle.getString("name")).removeValue();
            mTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item removed from cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: So is you're app crashing?

Comment: Not exactly ,when a app crashes it tends close itself, but here the application goes to the very last activity in android stack.

Comment: Then show us the code that you have used to navigate back.

Comment: Thats the thing I have not implemented anything to go back , its just the above code after which the above mentioned thing occures